# Separate records with comma

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php and I want to separate the records with a comma.

Database:
[the table in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zexs8.jpg)

I use this code to get the data:

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM  tablename
        WHERE parent_id=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "Test: " . $row["value"]. "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It return twice as:

```
Test: Test
Test: Test1
```

I want to separate the records with a ',' like this:

```
Test: Test, Test1
```

Comment: you need to learn more about the string to array, or array to string ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your values in an `array` and than implode with **","**. You will get the result:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM  tablename
        WHERE parent_id=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$yourArr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $yourArr[] = $row["value"];
    //echo "Test: " . $row["value"]. "<br>";
}
echo "Test: ". implode(",",$yourArr);
```

Comment: @HzrCan: well, now mark as accepted the best answer it will help for other who facing this issue also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely in MySQL using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();
$sql = "SELECT `parent_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`value` SEPARATOR ', ') AS comma_separated_values
        FROM tablename
        WHERE `parent_id` = '$id'
        GROUP BY `parent_id`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'Test: ' . $row["comma_separated_values"]; // Test: test, test2
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You should change the "comma_separated_values" name to something more appropriate for your data.

In your particular case, you would not need the `while()` loop either as we're limiting the MySQL to a single row.

If you were to remove the `WHERE`parent_id`= '$id'` from the SQL query, then you could return the results of multiple `parent_id` values. For example:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'Parent ' . $row['parent_id'] .': ' . $row["comma_separated_values"] . '<br>';
}
```

Would return:

Parent 292: Test1, Test2
Parent 293: Test3, Test4
Parent 294: Test5, Test10, Test50
etc...

Answer (score -1):

you can use update query for this

```
$query="Update tablename set value=CONCAT(value,',test1') where parentid='295'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```